# Class design: Last Modified

Tags: python, class-design

My class:

```
class ManagementReview:
    """Class describing ManagementReview Object.
    """

    # Class attributes
    id = 0
    Title = 'New Management Review Object'
    fiscal_year = ''
    region = ''
    review_date = ''
    date_completed = ''
    prepared_by = ''

    __goals = [] # List of <ManagementReviewGoals>.
    __objectives = [] # List of <ManagementReviewObjetives>.
    __actions = [] # List of <ManagementReviewActions>.
    __deliverables = [] # List of <ManagementReviewDeliverable>.
    __issues = [] # List of <ManagementReviewIssue>.

    __created = ''
    __created_by = ''
    __modified = ''
    __modified_by = ''
```

The __modified attribute is a datetime string in isoformat. I want that attribute to be automatically to be upated to datetime.now().isoformat() every time one of the other attributes is updated. For each of the other attributes I have a setter like:

```
def setObjectives(self,objectives):
    mro = ManagementReviewObjective(args)
    self.__objectives.append(mro)
```

So, is there an easier way to than to add a line like:

```
self.__modified = datetime.now().isoformat()
```

to every setter?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To update `__modified` when *instance* attributes are modified (as in your example of `self.__objectives`), you could override [`__setattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__).

For example, you could add this to your class:

```
def __setattr__(self, name, value):
    # set the value like usual and then update the modified attribute too
    self.__dict__[name] = value
    self.__dict__['__modified'] = datetime.now().isoformat()
```

Comment: Instead of `self.__dict__[name] = value`, I'd probably do `object.__setattr__(self, name, value)`.

Comment: I would recommend that, but he isn't using a new-style class since his class doesn't derive from `object`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps adding a decorator before each setter?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method that commits the changes made to these attributes to a database (like a save() method or update_record() method. Something like that), you could just append the

```
self.__modified = datetime.now().isoformat()
```

just before its all committed, since thats the only time it really matters anyway.